# Motor doesn't turn but makes noise

Tags: motor, fan

Motor that I took from electric fan doesn't turn, just makes buzzing noise. I had two fans, took motor from one and when I saw it doesn't work, I opened second one to check if I made something wrong. The moment I opened second one, it stopped working and now produces same buzzing noise.

What can be cause, capacitor from picture or something mechanical ?

Second motor I didn't open, just unscrewed marked screws (two are visible, and two more are on the other side), moved stator a little bit (1 cm) and put it back (that's why I think it can be something mechanical - maybe it needs good precision for creating magnetic field ?)

Opened motor is first one, to show what type it is.

First (disassembled one) and capacitor :

[image]

Second motor (mounted) :

[image: Second motor]

Answer (score 3):

If you disconnect the capacitor, the motor will not start by itself. The capacitor is connected in series with one of the windings to give the motor a "second phase." All single-phase motors have some feature like that to allow them to start by themselves in the proper direction. It might start if you give the shaft a turn to assist it. If you put the motor back together and turn the shaft with the power off, it should turn freely. If it doesn't, it is misaligned or has some other mechanical problem.

Comment: I don't know much about AC fan motors, but it might even be [run capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_capacitor#Run_capacitors) so needed for more than just start.

Comment: The capacitor is likely connected all the time even if it isn't needed for running because it is simpler and cheaper to make it that way.